# how to get the data that has the max values in column matrix data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get the cell that has max value, for example

```
  A   B  C
A 1   5  5
B 2   6  3
C 0.5 1  2
```

Output:

```
Max 5 -> (A,B), (A,C)
Max 6 -> (B)
Max 2 -> (C)
```

i have tried this

```
col_new = df.columns.values
row_new = df.index.values

for row, cols in df.iterrows():
    for col in range(len(df)):
        if col_new == df.max():
            print("Max (", row_new[row], ',', col_new[col], ')')
```

but the output is nothing

Comment: Have you made any attempts ? How do you store your data and how do you search for the max value ? Sorry but we cannot just write code for you

Comment: I understand. please see the edited, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
for row, cols in df.iterrows():
    max_value = cols.max()
    cols_list = cols[cols==max_value].index.tolist()

    if len(cols_list)>1:
        row_list = [row]*len(cols_list)
        tup = tuple(zip(row_list,cols_list))
        print(f'Max {max_value} -> {tup}')
    else:
        print(f'Max {max_value} -> {row,}')



Max 5.0 -> (('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'))
Max 6.0 -> ('B',)
Max 2.0 -> ('C',)
```

---

We are multiplying the list with number of max columns as:

```
print(['A']*3)
['A', 'A', 'A']
```

Comment: i see, thank you for your help. im still confused how to use if-else condition in pandas. could you please explain me this line -> row_list = [row]*len(cols_list) / what is * mean?

Comment: @Sujin Sure, since `row` from `df.iterrows()` is a string and if we have more than 1 max values in a row like in the first row. we are converting the string into a list and multiplying by the number of max columns in that row. check the update to see how it works.